# Is there a way to determine compile-time state of a kernel flag from a running system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration, btrfs

I have a running kernel and I'm trying to determine whether it was compiled with support for BTRFS extended attributes. Is there a way to determine a running kernel's compile flags?

Comment: Do you know what the configuration option is called? Is it in the mainline kernel yet?

Answer (score 2):

If kernel was compiled with CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC, you will have the original .config in `/proc/config.gz`

So in that case to see the full options:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz
```

Checking in my Armbian/Jessie with kernel 4.5.2 and BTRFS:

```
$zgrep -i btrfs /proc/config.gz 
CONFIG_BTRFS_FS=y
CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
# CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_CHECK_INTEGRITY is not set
# CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_RUN_SANITY_TESTS is not set
# CONFIG_BTRFS_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_BTRFS_ASSERT is not set
```

[Kernel/IKCONFIG Support](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/IKCONFIG_Support)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `sysctl`. It can be used to query and set kernel parameters.

`sudo sysctl -a` will display all current values.

Comment: sysctls are a completely different beast than kernel configuration